# How do I find out what's causing a page to temporarily render a horizontal scrollbar?

Tags: html, google-chrome, webkit, render

I'm looking at the following page:-

http://www.gearzap.com/

In Google's Chrome.

During page load, for some reason, a horizontal scrollbar appears for approximately half a second.

This is obviously something that's below the fold that's causing this, but I can't seem to find out what's causing the issue

EDIT:-  Video of this happening here:-

http://files.sourceguru.net/scrollbars.ogv

Comment: Interesting... I have actually no idea, but it's the same in firefox 4.

Comment: http://files.sourceguru.net/scrollbars.ogv <-- video of it happening

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a quick look (and man is there a lot of js on that page) and the navigation.js file jumped out at me.  I set the debugger and found that after 8 iterations of this loop:

```
$j('#navigation .submenu').each(function() {
    var obj = $j(this);
    var cols, w, l, offset;

    cols = obj.find('ul').length;

    obj.css('width', (cols * 200 + 16) + 'px');

    w = obj.outerWidth();
    l = obj.offset().left;
    offset = w + l;

    if(offset > max_w) {
        obj.animate({
            'margin-left' : '-=' + (offset - max_w) + 'px'
        });
    }
});
```

the scrollbar appears.

EDIT:  You may be able to just get away with turning that `obj.animate` into an `obj.css`.  If that doesn't work you might need to do the calculations prior to setting the css at all, rather than setting it, doing the calculations and then changing it again.  Not sure why that was ever an animate to begin with.

Comment: the animate function... damnit :D

Comment: I agree... not sure why there was an animate function myself either... !

Answer (score 0):

Actually it doesn't show for me. Not in Chrome nor firefox. Im using Chrome 12.0.742 for windows 7. I have checked over 10 times, but it never shows.

Maybe it has something to do with the version/settings of the browser used?

Comment: Nope - managed to reproduce this on multiple versions of chrome.

Comment: have you tried it with narrower browser widths? I'm assuming that if you are running widescreen enough that you may not see the horizontal scrollbar... (though I've not got chrome and a high res monitor to test at the moment. :)